# What was the original statement of Newton's Law of Cooling?

Tags: thermodynamics, cooling

In our courses of differential equations we usually find Newton's Law of Cooling stated and written as

> The rate of change of temperature of a body is directly proportional to the difference in temperature of the body and the surrounding at a time $$ \frac{dT}{dt} \propto (T_{surrounding} - T_{Body}) \\
> \frac{dT}{dt} = k (T_{surroudning}-T_{Body})$$

But in textbooks on thermodynamics and even on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_cooling) the mathematical form of the law is written as $$ \frac{dQ}{dt}= k (T_{surrounding}-T_{Body})$$.

So, which one was the originally given by the Sir Issac Newton? And which one is more useful? Please explain the difference in the two forms of the equation.

Comment: The introductory section of the Wikipedia article you linked seems to answer the question.

Comment: Exactly where did  you get the highlighted equations?

Comment: @hiccups No, that doesn’t answer my question. You see in that page it is written that *“Sir Isaac Newton did not originally state his law in the above form in 1701, when it was originally formulated. Rather, using today's terms, Newton noted after some mathematical manipulation that the rate of temperature change of a body is proportional to the difference in temperatures between the body and its surroundings*”.

Comment: @BobD In the OCW lectures on differential equation (by Prof. Arthur Mattuck).

Comment: @hiccups Wikipedia seems to be saying that Newton did not say “rate of heat loss of a body is directly proportional to temperature distance” but he formulated something else and through which mathematical manipulation he found “rate of change of temp. is directly proportional to temperature difference”.

Comment: @Knight I have never seen Newton's law of cooling written in terms of rate of temperature change. Look more related to the Fourier heat equation, but it isn't that either.

Comment: @BobD Thank you sir for searching it. You can see the [links](https://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math100/notes/diffeqs/cool.html) [here](https://math.illinoisstate.edu/day/courses/current/146/Notes/ch09sec03difeqapnewton.pdf)

Comment: @Knight Regarding your response to hiccups, you left out the rest, and most critical part of the Wiki statement, namely, that Newton's original formulation was wrong because of the confusion that existed between heat and temperature. That's why the law is not currently written that way.  So why are you presenting equations that are no longer considered valid? For what purpose?

Comment: @BobD Which equations are wrong?

Comment: @Knight The highlighted equations. The left side should be $\frac{dQ}{dT}$.

Comment: @BobD Yes. That is really my question. What was the original form that Newton gave his law in?

Comment: @Knight They appear to be based on the verbal description by Wiki. But personally i have never seen the actual original equations.

Answer (score 1):

> So, which one was the originally given by the Sir Issac Newton? And
>   which one is more useful? Please explain the difference in the two
>   forms of the equation.

I've never seen the actual original equations, but it appears that the highlighted ones were probably the original based on the Wiki discussion. However as Wiki points out:

*"Newton's law behavior, when stated in terms of temperature change in the body, also requires that internal heat conduction within the object be large in comparison to the loss/gain of heat by surface transfer (conduction and/or convection), which is the condition where the Biot number is less than about 0.1".*

That makes the usefulness of the original equations limited, and makes the second equation, with $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ on the left, more useful as less restrictions apply.

As pointed out in the Wikipedia article, one of the reasons for Newton's original formulation had $\frac{dT}{dt}$ on the left instead of $\frac {dQ}{dt}$ was because he, and others at the time, confused temperature with heat. A situation requiring another century to untangle.

As an aside, a more practical engineering version of Newton's Law of Cooling for steady heat flow is the following because it identifies the components of the proportionality constant.

$$\dot Q=hA(T_{w}-T_{∞})$$

where

$\dot Q$ = the heat transfer rate, $h$ = the heat transfer coefficient of the fluid, $A$ = the convection surface area, $T_w$ = the wall surface temperature and $T_∞$= the bulk 
fluid temperature.

Hope this helps.